# Disable Entity Framework pre-generated views via a config change?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Can I disable using Pre-generated views for a Entity Framework Context with a .config file change?

Comment: I don't think that is possible considering it is baked inside the .dll. 

Please let me know if you figure it out.

Comment: there has to be a way to override this feature Sam!!!!